# How to start a node.js app when Ubuntu server start up?

Tags: boot, server, reboot, nodejs

Sir,
   I have a node.js script call 'Test_timeevent.js'. I use 'forever' module to avoid timeevent.js crash. I hope when Ubuntu start,this 'forever' can start timeevent.js.  So,Test_timeevent.js will run always.
   The Test_timeevent.js code is below:

```
var schedule = require("node-schedule");
var rule1     = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
var times1    = [1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56];
var li_count=0;
rule1.second  = times1;
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule1, function(){
        li_count= li_count +1;
  console.log(li_count);
});
```

I write a run_vb.sh in the '/etc/init.d'  .The code is below：

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: barkelyhwang
# Required-Start: $all
# Required-Stop: $all
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: SMD service
# Description: timeevent service daemon
### END INIT INFO

forever start /home/barkely/nodeproject/vbs/Test_timeevent.js
exit 0
```

Then,I change run_vb.sh mode by：

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/run_vb.sh
```

And then,I execute 'update-rc.d' ：

```
sudo update-rc.d run_vb.sh defaults 99 1
```

After reboot my Ubuntu Server, I execute 'ps -aux',the result is：

```
root       1677  0.0  1.0 889064 45028 ?        Ssl  10:37   0:00 /usr/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor /home/barkely/nodeproject/vbs/Test_timeevent.js
root       1686  0.0  0.1  92828  6764 ?        Ss   10:37   0:00 sshd: barkely [priv]
root       1688  0.0  0.8 882192 36368 ?        Sl   10:37   0:00 /usr/bin/node /home/barkely/nodeproject/vbs/Test_timeevent.js
```

I find it seem to be executed,but when I check the output of forever of Test_timeevent.js,there are no output log. Normally,this folder should be like this：

```
barkely@barkelyVM:~/.forever$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  4 barkely barkely 4096 Nov 14 15:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 barkely barkely 4096 Nov 14 15:25 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 barkely barkely  293 Nov 14 15:34 config.json
drwxr-xr-x  2 barkely barkely 4096 Nov 14 15:35 pids
-rw-rw-r--  1 barkely barkely    4 Nov 14 15:35 **pQFQ.log**
drwxr-xr-x  2 barkely barkely 4096 Nov 14 15:34 sock
```

There is a log file called 'pQFQ.log'.

What step I lost?My script don't start when Ubuntu start.

My Ubuntu is  Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 LTS.
Node.js ：v10.5.0

Comment: Can you please replace the output of `ps -ax` with `ps -aux`. I assume it is a permission issue, because the servies is started with a differnt user then `barkely`

Comment: www-data   1662  0.0  0.2 325548  8672 ?        S    10:37   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root       1677  0.0  1.0 889064 45028 ?        Ssl  10:37   0:00 /usr/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor /home/barkely/nodeproject/vbs/Test_timeevent.js
root       1686  0.0  0.1  92828  6764 ?        Ss   10:37   0:00 sshd: barkely [priv]
root       1688  0.0  0.8 882192 36368 ?        Sl   10:37   0:00 /usr/bin/node /home/barkely/nodeproject/vbs/Test_timeevent.js
barkely    1694  0.0  0.1  45276  4592 ?        Ss   10:37   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user

Comment: Please add the output to your question. Use this link https://askubuntu.com/posts/1092771/edit

Comment: I don’t see anything in your script creating a log file at all. And the log file is from the `barkely` user, which is strange, because the nodejs process is owned by `root`.

While you’re a investigating, where the strange log file is coming from, I would advise to change your startup script to `systemd`. It makes it easier to monitor and debug the service